# Service Work and Push Notifications

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

I am currently trying to implement Push Notifications into my website and I am having trouble trying to display a dynamic title and link.

This is what my service worker currently looks like

```
self.addEventListener( 'push', function(event) {
    // console.log( '[Service Worker] Push Received.' );
    // console.log( '[Service Worker] Push has this data: ' );

    const title = event.data.title;
    const options = {
        body: event.data.text(),
    }

    const notificationPromise = self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
    event.waitUntil(notificationPromise);
} );

self.addEventListener( 'notificationclick', function( event ) {
    console.log( '[Service Worker] Notification click Received.' );

    event.notification.close();

    event.waitUntil(
        clients.openWindow( 'https://developers.google.com' )
    );
} )
```

As you can see currently the link is a hard-coded developers.google.com link and the title returns 'undefined'

[image: Screenshot of Notification]

Is there anything I have to do from the backend of the website to send these into the payload?

In case it helps I am using the [Web Push Library for C#](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-csharp)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is actually an issue with how you're accessing the title data from the json object.

To access the event.data object as a json object, you have to call the json() method on the data object. So something like this:

```
const title = event.data.json().title;
```